# Change multiple file names in a pattern

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, rename

I have a number of files with somewhat similar names:

```
HappyBD_Stereo_144kbps.mp3
HappyBD_Stereo_192kbps.mp3
HappyBD_Stereo_256kbps.mp3
...
```

For some reason, I need to change/shorten these names into something like

```
HappyBD_Ste_144k.mp3
HappyBD_Ste_192k.mp3
HappyBD_Ste_256k.mp3
...
```

Can someone recommend a good way to automate this kind of file name changes? Thanks.

Comment: Crossposting: http://askubuntu.com/questions/664029/change-multiple-file-names-in-a-pattern (already deleted with `rename` solution)

Answer (score 1):

you can try,

```
for filename in `ls *_Stereo_*.mp3`; do 
  newfilename=$(sed 's/_Stereo_/_Ste_/g' <<< $filename); 
  mv $filename $newfilename; 
done
```